# Cannot find the principal 'dbo', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server, dbo

This question is focussed on *why* this has happened.

We restored a database from another server that has failed.  The restore succeeded, but when we try and run any stored procedure (using 'sa' login, or Windows-based login with full admin access), we got this error:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo"
> does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you
> do not have permission.

Lots of SO users have had the same issue, so I followed the related answers.  For example, both of the following snippets:

```
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'dbo';
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDb TO dbo;
```

...result in this:

> Cannot find the principal 'dbo', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

On the previous server (and my restoration dev server) there is no `dbo` *user* to reassociate as the owner.  I'm not sure how to locate the *principal*, but it is listed in the Schema.

1. What causes 'dbo' to not be found, or what has happened to the dbo principal?
2. Can it be reinstated/recreated?
3. Does dbo have to link to an actual login account?

Comment: Has anybody ever made `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDb TO dbo` work? The target principal needs to be a Login as opposed to a (Database) User. Same goes for `sp_changedbowner`.

Comment: There's an answer on SO with 500 upvotes, so I guess so.  Didn't work here though!

Comment: For `alter authorization` generally, perhaps, but [alter authorization on database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql#alter-authorization-for-databases) cannot work using database principals - that would lead to a paradox and destroy the universe. See also [sp_changedbowner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changedbowner-transact-sql).

Answer (score 1):

The database owner is a server-level principal (i.e. login) or Windows user (not necessarily with a login). As noted in the comments, `dbo` is a database principal rather than a server principal (assuming you don't happen to have a login named `dbo`).

The owner is stored in the master database and visible as the `owner_sid` column of the `sys.databases` catalog view:

```
SELECT name AS DatabaseName, owner_sid, SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) AS OwnerName
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N'MyDb';
```

The database owner is also stored in the database itself as the well-known `dbo` user:

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(sid) AS OwnerName, sid
FROM sys.database_principals AS dp
WHERE name = N'dbo';
```

When a database is restored and it doesn't already exist, the owner (authorization) is initially set to the person who restored the database. However, the `dbo` entry in the database itself remains unchanged. This results in a mismatch between the owner in `sys.databases` and the `sys.database_principals` `dbo` user. It is necessary to execute `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE` with the desired owner after a restore to correct the mismatch.

Below is a script that demonstrates the issue when the individual executing the restore is not logged in as `sa`.

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDb; --database is owned by current login

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDb TO sa; --sa is an example; can be any login

--shows owners are same (sa)
SELECT name AS DatabaseName, owner_sid, SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) AS OwnerName
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N'MyDb';

SELECT SUSER_SNAME(sid) AS OwnerName, sid
FROM MyDb.sys.database_principals AS dp
WHERE name = N'dbo';

BACKUP DATABASE MyDb TO DISK=N'C:\Backups\MyDb.bak' WITH INIT;

DROP DATABASE MyDb;

RESTORE DATABASE MyDb FROM DISK=N'C:\Backups\MyDb.bak';

--shows owners are different (current user and sa)
SELECT name AS DatabaseName, owner_sid, SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) AS OwnerName
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N'MyDb';

SELECT SUSER_SNAME(sid) AS OwnerName, sid
FROM MyDb.sys.database_principals AS dp
WHERE name = N'dbo';

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDb TO sa; --sa is an example; can be any login

--shows owners are same (sa)
SELECT name AS DatabaseName, owner_sid, SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) AS OwnerName
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N'MyDb';

SELECT SUSER_SNAME(sid) AS OwnerName, sid
FROM MyDb.sys.database_principals AS dp
WHERE name = N'dbo';
```

Below is an excerpt from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#alter-authorization-for-databases) regarding the database owner principal.

> The new owner principal must be one of the following:
>
> ```
> A SQL Server authentication login.
> A Windows authentication login representing a Windows user (not a group).
> A Windows user that authenticates through a Windows authentication login representing a Windows group.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for a very clear answer.  The second code sample produces now rows, so I ran this which completed successfully, `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDatabase TO [AzureAD\MyName];`.  However, running the second code sample again still returns no rows, but in Properties my name is listed.  Running a proc from the database produces, *Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'AzureAD\MyName', error code 0x54b.*  Why might that occur please?